# Domain is pointing to a different app in Heroku even after setting CNAME in DNS provider

Tags: heroku, dns

After setting the provided host from Heroku as a CNAME record in my DNS provider my domain is loading *a site that is not mine*. http://foodbae.com.ng is my address but the site that is loading is not mine! What is the issue here. I have set the www CNAME record to the host Heroku provided so I don't know why it is loading an app that is not even mine :/

Answer (score 0):

There was a previous app that used that domain on Heroku. After a while, it was pointing to my app correctly.